# How do I search for text within comments and logs in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I am using shift-shift to search for part of a text within a log output 
or comment 
eg // iterate index
eg Log.d("dbug","Iterate complete")

How do I find the comment that contains the work "iterate"
The search seems to find everything else ecvept comments and logs 
My log cat dosent show the line number of the log output, that would be another solution?

Comment: the a search box to filter logs above logcat

Answer (score 0):

open the logcat tab in android studio

[image]

type the phrase you want to search eg:

[image]

you can also search for multiple phrases using regex expressions

[image]

hope this helps.